# What happens if my non-renewing in-app purchase receipt is lost before it can be registered on my server?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm currently implementing a non-renewable in-app purchase and am a little concerned over the following scenario (or variation thereof):

User purchases my non-renewing in-app purchase. I save the receipt to NSUserDefaults, but before I have sent it to my own server for verification (and account functionality activation) the user loses signal/my server is down and in the meantime breaks their device/uninstalls my app (thus erasing the stored NSUserDefaults).

As far as I can tell you cannot restore a non-renewable purchase as with other types of IAP, so the user has lost the money they spent on that purchase as there is no way for me to know that it was ever made.

Am I missing something here, or am I to assume the above scenario is unlikely enough that I needn't worry about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some further reading it appears that the solution is to not call `finishTransaction` on the `SKPaymentTransaction` until I have had confirmation from my server. This way, the transaction should remain in the transaction queue across devices/installations until I have registered it within my own system.